# Include Path error in VS Code in Repo pulled from GitHub

Tags: 20.04, paths, visual-studio-code, github

I recently cloned a repo from Github which was made by me and pushed to github using windows. Now, when I run any code file from the repo in VS code it gives me include path error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHT0f.png)

Comment: Please copy/paste and format text instead of pictures of text. A picture (of text) can't be read on a text-only terminal, can't be copied from (edited, tried, and made to work), AND makes one take an action to even read your Question. Since we're all volunteers, some won't click. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting